# Unknow SMTP host android JavaMail

Tags: java, android

I have a Mailserver, which is hosted at the same network as my phone, but I keep getting an exception saying `Unknow SMTP host`. I've read several places that this exception occurs when the hostname isnt correct spelled, of course. But in this case it **IS**. In `C#` its done a simple way like this:

```
var client = new SmtpClient(_strSmtpHost);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 
var mailMessage = new MailMessage(_strFrom, emailTo);
mailMessage.Subject = subject;
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

And in my application its done this way:

```
 SendMail m = new SendMail("Username", "password"); 

      String[] toArr = {"TO@EXAMPLE.com"};   
      m.setTo(toArr); 
      m.setFrom("FROM@EXAMPLE.com"); 
      m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
      m.setBody("Email body."); 

      try { 
        m.addAttachment(fileName); 

        if(m.send()) { 
          Log.i("MAIL SENDER: ", "Succesfully");
        } else { 
              Log.i("MAIL SENDER: ", "UnSuccesfully");
        } 
      } catch(Exception e) { 
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email" + e); 
      }
```

In my SendMail class I define a String containing the `DNS` address of the host

```
_host = "napserver"; // default smtp server
_port = "25"; // default smtp port
```

Before I try to do a connect, I want to Authenticate username and password for the mail-address sending the mail:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new GMailAuthenticator(_user, _pass));
```

and then trying to a connect and send message

```
  Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
  transport.connect(_host, 25, _user, _pass);
  Transport.send(msg);
```

Just for testing purposes I tried the `SMTP` address for Gmail, and this worked, and the mail was sent to the specified mail account. Can anybody give me a hint?

**EDIT**

I should also mention that I tried to connect via `Telnet` to this mail server, and the ouput from PuTTy, when connected with the host `napserver` and port `25` :

```
220 napserver.nap01.dac.no.eu-admin.net Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6                                               .0.3790.3959 ready at  Tue, 7 Aug 2012 13:38:55 -0700
```

**EDIT 2**

As you can see from the PuTTy output:

```
Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service
```

My mailserver uses the ESMTP, but as far as I know this just implements some security layers and so on. Maybe this is where the error is?

**EDIT 3**

I tried to access the mailserver via remote desktop, I pinging my phones IP-address just to be sure that the server and the phone is located on the same network, and it is..

Comment: Try using the fully qualified domain name in your code instead of just "napserver"

Comment: I tried this `napserver.nap01.dac.no.eu-admin.net` as the host name, the exception is thrown after about 1 minute.